# How to disable cmd pop-ups in Android SDK?

Tags: android, sdk, cmd, popup

since I updated my Android SDK to Android 5.0 API 21, it's always showing several cmd pop ups (aapt.exe) for some milliseconds while building projects in eclipse. It's really annoying. How may I disable this behaviour?

Thanks